# Call Function in Dynamic HTML String

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, onclick

I have a structure in my application where I generate dynamic html. I add an html member in each user action and this member has buttons. I want to assign my defined function to the (onclick) action of these buttons. However, when I click the buttons in my instantaneously generated html string, I get the error that the relevant function is undefined. What can I do about it?
My functions;

```
returnButtonGroup(key: string):string{
    return '<i onclick="testFunc(\'' +key + '\');" class="fa fa-wrench"></i>'
}
testFunc(key:string){
    console.log(key);
}
```

I add i tags by using innerHtml in every action of the user. Any suggestions on what I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to consider the scoping and context of the functions you're trying to bind.

In your case, the testFunc function is defined in your Angular component, but it's being invoked from an inline onclick attribute within the generated HTML string. This can lead to scope and context issues.

To properly bind events and functions within dynamically generated HTML in Angular, you should utilize Angular's event binding mechanism.

Update your returnButtonGroup function to return Angular template code instead of raw HTML strings. Use Angular's (click) event binding to bind the testFunc function.

```
returnButtonGroup(key: string): string {
  return `<i (click)="testFunc('${key}')" class="fa fa-wrench"></i>`;
}
```

in Html use

```
<div [innerHTML]="dynamicHtml"></div>
```

In your component.ts, create a property that holds the dynamically generated HTML and make sure the testFunc function is accessible within the component.

```
dynamicHtml: string;

constructor() {
  this.dynamicHtml = this.returnButtonGroup('someKey'); // Call your method here with the appropriate key
}

testFunc(key: string) {
  console.log(key);
}
```